# Scraping Google Translate Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

As a Challenge to my self I'm trying to scrape translations from google translate. I download the html file by a browser simulated request and then using beautifulSoupe 4 I try finding the translation in the html code. The problem is that although I can find what I want in Chrome WebDev Mode I cant do such thing in Python or using another program such as noteblock. Here is my code:

```
while Translating==True:
text=input(("Values to translate:"))
#CREATING URL TO SCRAPE
translator_url_with_translation_embebed= translator_url+ EncodeTexttoURL(text)
#REQUESTING PAGE WITH FAKE HEADERS (avoiding no browser detection)
url = translator_url_with_translation_embebed
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response= requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
#ANALISING RESPONSE FOR FURTHER USE
sopa = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

translation_location=sopa.find_all('span', {'class' : 'tlid-translation translation'})
print("TRANSLATED LOCATIOON")
print(translation_location
```

`
translation_location outputs an empty list.

Browser Dev mode showing translation in html code:

[image: Browser Dev mode showing translation in html code]

How can i find them? Are the translations elsewhere? Did google sent a modified version of their website to fool me?!

Thanks for the help

Comment: What does `print(response.text)` give?

Comment: I think you ll find this interesting: https://pypi.org/project/deep-translator/

Answer (score 4):

translated word are coming from XMLHttpRequest and beautifulsoup cannot handle this. duplicate the request (complicated) or use Selenium. But I think it easier to just use [googletrans](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans) library.

```
$ pip install googletrans
```

then your code

```
from googletrans import Translator

while Translating==True:
    translator = Translator()
    text=input(("Values to translate:"))
    translation = translator.translate(text, dest='en')
    print(translation.text)
```

Comment: but what if I just want the HTML code has seen in Dev Mode? How do I get that? That should work with BeautifulSoup! Interestingly enough BS never really gave an error, but any ways since its a XMLHttpRequest it means that the info we get is parcial, but from what i understood, really in the same format has .html, right?

Comment: you can't because it generated by Javascript and BS not execute JS code. to get the content, in dev tools switch to Network tab and watch URL start with `translate.google.com/translate_a/single...` and duplicate this request

Comment: oh I see.. and that URL changes in a non linear way, therefore in order to duplicate it we would need to build some features of an web browser... Thxx I will take a look into Selenium and manage a way around this. Thx for the help

Comment: Selenium using more CPU resource, I will use that library instead or learn how they work.

Comment: It seems the translation results of Google API is different from the results directly query from the website "translate.google.com". How to resolve the problem? The website translation seem more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
py -m pip install "googletrans"
py -m pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1
py -m pip install beautifulsoup4


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.formatter import HTMLFormatter
from googletrans import Translator
import requests

translator = Translator()
```

**Check the complete Python code here:**

https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/python-code-text-google-translate-website-translation-beautifulsoup-library.html

OR HERE:

https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/example-google-translate-api-key-python-code-beautifulsoup.html